# facing issues with django forms

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

i am facing some issue in django forms. Problem is even though i put this code "attrs={'class': 'form-control'}" but when ever go to site and inspect-element, html doesn't include this class

it shows this...

```
<input id="id_name" maxlength="100" name="name" type="text" required="">
```

as you can see it didn't render 'class':'form-control'

I might be doing something wrong please tell me how to solve this problem???

forms.py, view.py and .html file code is given below

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import ContactUs


class ContactUsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})),
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True),
    subject = forms.CharField(required=True),
    message = forms.CharField(
        required=True,
        widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
    ),
    class Meta:
        model = ContactUs
        fields = ['name', 'email', 'subject', 'message']
```

**contact.html**

```
<div class="container main-container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-offset-1 col-xs-10 col-md-offset-1 col-md-5">
        <h5>Contact Us</h5>
        <form method="POST" action="/contact/">{% csrf_token %}
            {% for fields in form %}
            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="{{ fields.id_for_label }}">{{ fields.label }}</label>
            {{ fields }}
            </div>
            {% endfor %}
            <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

**views.py**

```
from .forms import ContactUsForm
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib import messages
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

def Contact(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ContactUsForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            model_instance = form.save()
            messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, 'YOUR FORM HAS BEEN SUBMITTED')
            return redirect('/contact/')
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/admin/')
    else:
        return render(request, 'core/contact.html', {'form': ContactUsForm()})
```

Answer (score 0):

Just update your forms.py class like below then it will add form field attribute.

## forms.py

```
class ContactUsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ContactUsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['description'].widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
        self.fields['message'].widget = forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})

    name = forms.CharField(required=True)
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    subject = forms.CharField(required=True)
    message = forms.CharField(required=True)
    class Meta:
        model = ContactUs
        fields = ['name', 'email', 'subject', 'message']
```

Comment: is there something wrong with my previous forms.py, can please tell why my code wasn't working

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/widgets/#widget
This will help you to find out why your forms.py is not working.